# Check if a column value is numeric in pandas dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, data-cleaning

I have a dataset that I want to clean. The data set consists of 54 columns and 315 rows. For one of the columns, I want to find whether all the values in that column are numeric or not. I have done the following:

```
work_sheet = pd.read_excel('2006_sale.xlsx', sheet_name='Sheet1')
df = work_sheet.copy()
```

**TRY 1**

```
for idx,val in enumerate(df['LotArea']):
    if(not(str(val).isnumeric())):        # Check if a value is numeric or not
        df.at[idx,'LotArea'] = np.nan     # If the value is not numeric then replace it with null
```

**TRY 2**

```
for idx,val in enumerate(df['LotArea']):
    if(not(isinstance(val,float))):        # Check if a value is numeric or not
        df.at[idx,'LotArea'] = np.nan     # If the value is not numeric then replace it with null
```

Sample values of LotArea is:
[image]

**Problem with both the approach**
Somehow it is detecting each value as non-numeric and my final output looks like this:
[image]

Any idea where i am going wrong?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

A for loop is not needed to achieve this. You can use the pd.to_numeric method and by setting errors to 'coerce', all non-numeric values will be replaced with NaN.

```
df['LotArea'] = pd.to_numeric(df['LotArea'], errors='coerce')
```

Comment: cool, Nice one!

Comment: Ah! i should not iterate over columns using loop. Nice and quick answer. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

first I would like to drop this link here.
for-loop in pandas is anti-pattern and there are many performant way to achieve data transformation without using the for-loop. Please check the link.

https://stackoverflow.com/a/55557758/2956135

To answer your question, use `replace` function with a regex.

```
df['LotArea'] = df.LotArea.replace(regex='|[^\d+]', value=np.nan)
```

Comment: Thanks Emma! The link shared by you is very handy, specially the "DONT's" part.